# use of an overloaded operator in a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, operator-keyword

i'm writing a program where you can give an object an integer and it calculates the next bigger prime number. The task is to overload the prefix operator and use it in the constructor, so that if i create an object and give it the number 11, it should store the next bigger prime number (13).

my operator overload looks like this:

```cpp
cPrimZahl& cPrimZahl::operator++()
{
    nextprim = prim;
    while (!is_Prime(nextprim))
    {
        ++nextprim;
        if (nextprim > 10000)
        {
            while (!is_Prime(nextprim))
            {
                --nextprim;
            }
            prim = nextprim;
            break;
        }
        prim = nextprim;
    }

    cout << "die naechst groessere Primzahl ist: " << prim << endl;

    return *this;
}
```

main:

```cpp
int main(){
    cPrimZahl obj(13);  // The object here is 13 now
    ++obj1;             // Here its 17

    return 0;
}
```

my constructor:

```cpp
cPrimZahl::cPrimZahl(int prim_in)
{
    if (prim_in > maxprim)  // maxprim = 10000
    {
        cout << "Prime number is to big! Adjusting..." << endl;
        prim = 1;
    }

    else if (prim_in < 0)
    {
        cout << "Prime number can't be negative! Adjusting..." << endl;
        prim = 1;
    }

    prim = prim_in;
    ++prim;   // at this point i want it to increment to give me the next bigger prime number
}
```

i tried a lot of methods now but i just always get a regular increment... The operator overload comes before the construcot, but i also tried to put the constructor before the overload, neither works. What else can i do?

Comment: you can call `++(*this)` in the constructor. It will call the prefix operator on the current object.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor `prim` refers to the `prim` member (which is presumably of some integer type). `++prim` therefore is using the built-in pre-increment operator for that integer type, which will increment the `prim` member by one.

You don't want to call the pre-increment operator on the `prim` member, but on the current object itself.

The current object can be obtained using `*this`, so that calling the pre-increment operator on it would be done with `++(*this);`.

Alternatively you can call to the overload directly treating it like an ordinary member function using the function call syntax: `operator++();`

Comment: Thanks, that one did it for me! Finally understanding the this operator. ^^

Comment: @marcopasta `this` is not an operator, it is a pointer to the current object and so `*this` is a reference to the current object.

Comment: @marcopasta You are not supposed to write comments purely to say "Thank you" here. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for what you can (but don't have to) do instead when someone answers your question.